# Display Value on Textbox on selection of Dropdownlist option

Tags: javascript, jsp

i want to display a value in textbox based on selection of Combobox.. my code is below

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Account Open Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function selectvalue(acct)
{
 var savingamt=1000;
 var currentamt=500;
 var selectedText = acct.options[acct.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var selectedValue = acct.value;
   
   
    if (current) {      
      alert("Account Type is  " + selectedText + "  and " + selectedValue);
     document.getElementById("depositamt").value = currentamt;
    } else if (saving) {
     alert("Account Type is  " + selectedText + "  and " + selectedValue);
     document.getElementById("depositamt").value = savingamt;
    } 
   
}


</script>
</head>
<body>


<form name="frmAccount" action="com.bank.Handler.RegHandler" method="post">
<table>


<tr>
<td>Account Type</td>
<td>
<select name="cmbacttype" id="acct" onchange="selectvalue(this)">
<option value="">---Select Account Type---</option>
<option value="Deposit Amount Should be minimum 1000 Rupee" id="saving">Saving Account</option>
<option value="Deposit Amount Should be minimum 500 Rupee" id="current">Current Account</option>
</select>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Deposit Amount</td>
<td><input type="text" name="deposit" id="depositamt"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Enter Amount</td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Total Amount</td>
<td><input type="text" name="totalamount" id="totalamount"></td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

from the above code, on Selection of saving account 1000 value should get display on **Deposit Amount** textbox and on selection of current account it should display 500 value.
in javascript code , its displaying only the value of current , but if i select saving account it did not do anything... how can we display saving account value  on selection of saving account option?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `current` inside your if condition. I do not know where you are getting the value of `current`. Looks like it is missing. If you add this line before accessing that in your if condition, It will work.

```
var current = selectedText==="Current Account"; 
if (current) {  
}
else {
}
```

The expression  `selectedText==="Current Account"` will return true or false based on the value of selectedText variable and you are good to use current in your if condition now.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/hezisu/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.

Comment: <select name="cmbacttype" id="acct" onchange="selectvalue(this)">
<option value="">---Select Account Type---</option>
<option value="Deposit Amount Should be minimum 1000 Rupee" id="saving">Saving Account</option>
<option value="Deposit Amount Should be minimum 500 Rupee" <id>id="current"></id>Current Account</option>
</select> 


<b>i am getting the current value from my html code as id="current" as mentioned in above html code</b>

Comment: Thanks a lot Shyju... its working for me you saved my day..  thank you

Comment: `Id` is not a valid attribute for the `OPTION` . See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option